# What's the cleanest way to export React components as an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This code works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to clean it up.

I'm making a library of SVG patterns and want to create a dashboard that lists each pattern, very similar to [this site](https://heropatterns.com). Each of the patterns is a React component, and I'm exporting them as an array from an `index.js` file:

```js
import FirstPattern from "./FirstPattern";
import SecondPattern from "./SecondPattern";
import ThirdPattern from "./ThirdPattern";
import FourthPattern from "./FourthPattern";
import FifthPattern from "./FifthPattern";
import SixthPattern from "./SixthPattern";
// ...and about 100 more...

export default [
  FirstPattern, 
  SecondPattern, 
  ThirdPattern,
  FourthPattern,
  FifthPattern,
  SixthPattern,
  // ...and about 100 more...
];
```

This lets me map through them on the dashboard:

```js
import patterns from "./patterns";

function PatternDashboard() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#ff0000");
  const [background, setBackground] = useState("#000000");

  return (
    <>
      {patterns.map((Pattern, id) => (
        <Pattern
          key={`icon${id}`}
          color={color}
          background={background}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to structure my `index.js` file so it isn't so repetitive?

Comment: Not if you're set on the import being an array.

Answer (score 1):

Just a nudge towards not doing as an array is to consider doing an `import * as patterns from './patterns'` and then you wouldn't have to list them twice in your index file:

```
export { default as FirstPattern } from './FirstPattern';
export { default as SecondPattern } from './SecondPattern';
...
```

```
import * as patterns from './patterns';

Object.keys(patterns).... // (or Object.values/Object.entries)
```

(Too long for a comment, I know this is not an answer).